# Как вытащить уникальные слова в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

```
coalesce(case when main_parse_user.bio is distinct from EXCLUDED.bio
      and EXCLUDED.bio is not null 
     then concat(trim(main_parse_user.bio), ' ', trim(EXCLUDED.bio)) 
     else main_parse_user.bio end)
```

Эта часть моего кода для добавление в бд

Туда приходит текст и код должен сравнить то что пришло и то что в бд и надо брать из текста который вводился те слова которых нету в бд

ПРИМЕР

```
То что в базе
|id|bio|
| 1|qwerty|

INPUT
|id|bio|
| 1|qwerty new|

База после INSERT
|id|     bio     |
| 1|qwerty | new |
```

Как можно такое сделать?

Полный код

```
INSERT INTO main_parse_user ("user_id","group_id", "username","bio", "first_name","url") VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) 
ON CONFLICT (user_id) 
DO UPDATE SET (group_id,username,bio,first_name) = (EXCLUDED.group_id,EXCLUDED.username, coalesce(case when main_parse_user.bio is distinct from 
EXCLUDED.bio and EXCLUDED.bio is not null then 
concat(trim(main_parse_user.bio), ' | ', trim(EXCLUDED.bio)) else main_parse_user.bio 
end  ),EXCLUDED.first_name)'''
```

НОВАЯ ЧАСТЬ

```
INSERT INTO main_parse_user 
("user_id","group_id", "username", "bio", "first_name","url") 
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ON CONFLICT (user_id) 
DO UPDATE SET (group_id,username,bio,first_name) = (EXCLUDED.group_id,EXCLUDED.username,
(SELECT array_agg(f order by f) FROM (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(main_parse_user.bio) as x(f) UNION 
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(EXCLUDED.bio)  as x(f)) d),EXCLUDED.first_name)
```

Все ли я правильно сделал в своем варианте?

У меня код выдает ошибку как `InvalidTextRepresentation`

Cтруктура БД

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.main_parse_user
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('main_parse_user_id_seq'::regclass),
    user_id bigint,
    group_id bigint,
    username character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    bio text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    first_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    url text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT main_parse_user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT main_parse_user_user_id_key UNIQUE (user_id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.main_parse_user
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Comment: вот сюда `VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ` скорее всего приходит не то, что Постгрис ожидает. Попробуй тут константы с правильным типом вместо `%s`, чтобы убедиться, что проблема уйдёт

Comment: Я поставил разные виды но не помогло, я даже поставил напрямую значения ```VALUES ('{i[1]}', '{i[0]}', '{i[2]}', '{i[3]}', '{i[4]}', '{link}')``` но и это не помогло и даже ввел сами данные но и они не помогли (

Comment: Очевидно же, что все значения выше негодные константы. Д.б. что-то вроде `VALUES(1, 2, 'some_user', '{"a","b"}'::text[], 'some_name', 'some_url')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я советую хранить `bio` как массив строк `text[]`, это упрощает работу

Ниже как бы выглядел код, если бы `bio` был массивом

```
create table tbl (id int primary key, bio text[]);
```

---

```
insert into tbl (id, bio) 
select 2 as id, string_to_array('a b c', ' ') as bio
on conflict(id)
do update set bio = (
  select array_agg(f order by f) from (
    select * from unnest(tbl.bio) as x(f)
    union 
    select * from unnest(EXCLUDED.bio)  as x(f)
  ) d
);


insert into tbl (id, bio) 
select 2 as id, string_to_array('d a e c', ' ') as bio
on conflict(id)
do update set bio = (
  select array_agg(f order by f) from (
    select * from unnest(tbl.bio) as x(f)
    union 
    select * from unnest(EXCLUDED.bio)  as x(f)
  ) d
);


select * from tbl;
```

| id | bio |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | a,b,c,d,e |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/0)

---

Переписать на хранение текста с разделителем `|` тоже можно, но это уже сам.

Comment: можно ли создать такой массив в Django ORM ?

Comment: Из джанго можно присылать строку, в моём примере на входе строка, которая парсится в массив.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

Comment: можете посмотреть в  чем моя ошибка в коде